# display list from complex json using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, html-lists, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this JSON (I did not create it and can not change it)

```
{"tags": [
    {
      "title": "news",
      "options": [
          {
            "title": "important",
          },
          {
            "title": "less important",
          }
         ]
    },
    {
       "title": "entertainment",
       "options": [
           {
              "title": "entertainment",
           }
          ]
     }
```

I would like to display it as a list, where if a certain title hasonly one option then the title should be displayed in the list, and if a title has more than one item in options, then the main title should be displayed and the options titles should also be displayed.
the final result (according to the above example) should display:

```
 <ul>
     <li>news<ul>
                <li>important</li>
                <li>less important</li>
             </ul>
        </li>
    <li>entertainment</li>
  </ul>
```

how can I do this in angularJS?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates

Answer (score 3):

You can try with something like that if `myList` is the name that you use in the `$scope` for the json object. 
Basically is an `ng-repeat` with an inner `ng-repeat`

```
<ul ng-repeat="element in myList.tags">
    <li>
        {{element.title}}
        <ul ng-repeat="innerElement in element.options">
            <li>{{innerElement.title}}</li>
        </ul>
     </li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your json file is stored in a variable called result

```
<ul ng-repeat = "tg in result.tags">
   <li ng-if="tg.options.length > 1">{{tg.title}}
      <ul ng-repeat ="innerElement in tg.options" >
         <li>{{innerElement.title}}</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li ng-if="tg.options.length==1">{{tg.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thnx, both above suggestions helped clear out the solution.
I needed to nest two `ng-repeat` loops together and apply an `ng-if` to the inner loop.

I ended up with this soultion:

`<ul>
       <li ng-repeat="x in myData.tags">
         {{x.title}}
         <ul ng-repeat="y in x.options" ng-if="x.options.length>1">
            {{y.title}}
         </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>`